# Can't get CORS working for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I have two applications running locally. One is an ASP.NET Core Web API (http://localhost:8081) serving up JSON responses. The other is a Javascript app (http://localhost:8080) making calls to the API. The API endpoint I'm testing with is a POST request and I've confirmed with Fiddler that this endpoint is working.

When I make the POST request from my Javascript app in Chrome I see this error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8081/api/search: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

However, this is the full content of my API's `Startup`:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters()
        .AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("DefaultCorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                    .AllowAnyMethod());
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("DefaultCorsPolicy");

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I've followed the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors), so I'm not sure what I've missed.

Here is the raw response I get from this endpoint in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 10 Mar 2018 09:23:46 GMT
Content-Length: 37

[{"id":1,"name":"lorem ipsum dolor"}]
```

As you can see, no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present.

Comment: Can you show us the response message when calling http://localhost:8081 ?

Comment: I've added to the end of my question. I've also re-ordered the `UseCors` and `UseMvc` statements after reading this (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas), but this hasn't changed the behaviour.

Comment: Working well for me, try rebuilding the API solution.

Comment: @getsetcode try to add `.AllowAnyHeader()` as well

Comment: @orel-eraki Thanks for checking. I've rebuilt many times with many variations of the configuration. I must be missing something but I can't imagine what.

Comment: @Set Thanks, but I've even tried with .AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader() and still no headers :(

Comment: This has suddenly started working. Can't explain why or how because the code is still as above. I did an iisreset but wasn't the first time I'd tried that. Wish I understood why it wasn't working before.

Comment: A similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900141/asp-net-core-cors-request-blocked-why-doesnt-my-api-apply-the-right-headers

Answer (score 2):

You can try to configure CORS options right in services.UseCors() call, rather than services.AddCors().

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvcCore();
    ...
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8000")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
    );

    app.UseMvcCore();
    ...
}
```

> Note: Test it by Clearing the client side cache if any. On Chrome > F12 > Network Tab > Tick *Disable Cache* check box > Refresh the page.