# CORS are not working with Angular 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core API and application in Angular 5. I have added code in Startup.cs to enable cors and to allow all origin, but still, it is giving me an error that

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Below is my web api code:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        WriteToFile("In configure service");
        try
        {
            // Enable Cors
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        catch
        {
            WriteToFile("Not Connected in StartUP");
        }
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        try
        {
            app.UseCors(builder =>
               builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod());

            app.UseMvc();

            WriteToFile("After cors use In configure");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToFile("Error in  configure"+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It will give you that error, if saying a service can not be injected. Try to look more clearly is that error is exactly about CORS

Comment: Sorry i am new to angular and web api , but how to find the root cause

Comment: Remote the constructor params from that controller to which you navigate first and check if it goes into the constructor

Comment: No Its not giving in that controller constructor, but still i am not sure why it is like this. can you please help me

Comment: @Roshan04 do you send [credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests) with a request?

Comment: Yes I use token

Comment: I http post request I am sending username and password.

Comment: There is a server error, is not related to CORS.

Comment: You can resolve the same in the following way that I already posted a solution here, how to make CORS working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207455/cant-get-cors-working-for-asp-net-core-web-api?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you should put

```
[EnableCors(origins: "**http:/...(Here the website you want to enter)**", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

just before the class in your Controller.